# Why is my Jersey JAX-RS server throwing a IllegalStateException about not being in RequestScope?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I've been looking at this one for too long and found the solution and wanted to provide feedback for any other intrepid JAX-RS adventurers that follow.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.current(RequestScope.java:226)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:154)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.MethodInterceptorImpl.intercept(MethodInterceptorImpl.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.UriInfoInjectee$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4cfd1aab.toString(<generated>)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at au.csiro.esa.authrest.rest.resource.PingResource.setUriInfo(PingResource.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1011)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:816)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:801)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.CdiComponentProvider$1.inject(CdiComponentProvider.java:316)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:103)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    at au.csiro.esa.authrest.rest.resource.PingResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.ping(Unknown Source)
....
```

Its a simple Resource marked as `@RequestScoped`

```
@Path("ping")
@RequestScoped
public class PingResource {

    protected UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Context
    public void setUriInfo(UriInfo uriInfo) {
        System.out.println("UserResource - set uriInfo:"+uriInfo);
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
    }

    @Inject
    @PropertiesFile(name = "app")
    Properties properties;

    @PermitAll
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    public Response ping() {
        System.out.println("Hit ping");
        return Response.ok().entity("Running version " + properties.getProperty("application.version")).build();
        // return Response.ok().entity("Running version 10").build();
    }
    ....
```

Comment: I've created issue https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2241 for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is the `@Context` on the `URIInfo`.  It has to be like:

```
public void setUriInfo(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        System.out.println("UserResource - set uriInfo:"+uriInfo);
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
    }
```

or

```
@Context
protected UriInfo uriInfo;
```

Seems obvious doesn't it!  The exception mentions URIInfo so what was my problem?  I dunno, I can only think that I saw something exactly like this error, caused by something else and I changed things around to be incorrect (like in the big block of code you see at the top).  The exception seemed to be the same and it didn't click that I'd actually caused a different error.

Anyway, I'm walking away, tail between my legs and feeling somewhat happy that I worked out the cause of the problem and the solution.  There was nothing on the 'net so I thought I'd share this with you 'all.