# Jersey JAX-RS Glassfish 4 throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: rest, glassfish-4.1

I am creating a simple RESTful service

```
@Path("/book")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Stateless
public class RestBookService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="bookPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Context
    protected UriInfo uriInfo;

    @POST
    public Response createBook(Book book) {
        if (book == null)
            throw new BadRequestException();
        em.persist(book);
        URI bookUri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(book.getId() + "").build();
        return Response.created(bookUri).build();
    }
}
```

The Book is simple JPA entity

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Book {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Book.class.getName());

    public static final String FIND_ALL = "Book.find_all";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String title;

    @Column
    private Float price;
}
```

//Just giving a relevant code. There are getters/setters and the constructor

I am deploying the service using Maven on Glassfish 4.1
I am using
Jersey Container 2.13
Hibernate 4.3.5 Final
Mysql 5.1

and when I try to create a book using cURL as follows

```
curl -X POST --data-binary "<book><price>12.5</price><title>Book Title</title></book>" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" http://localhost:8080/book-service/rs/book -v
```

It is throwing following exception.

```
  StandardWrapperValve[jersey-serlvet]: Servlet.service() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.current(RequestScope.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.MethodInterceptorImpl.invoke(MethodInterceptorImpl.java:74)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.MethodInterceptorInvocationHandler.invoke(MethodInterceptorInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy239.getAbsolutePathBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at com.services.bookrestservice.rest.RestBookService.createBook(RestBookService.java:44)
```

[There is another question similar to this but I have done exactly the same which is given in the answer still I am getting the exception. Also, I have gone through https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2241 but it seems to be in resolved state with the resolution as cannot reproduce. ]

Can somebody please help me.

### **EDIT1**

I have changed from Stateless annotation to RequestScoped annotation as suggested by @HankCa. It is throwing following exception now.

```
'javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTxRequiredCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:161)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTransactionScopedTxCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:151)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:281)
    at com.services.bookrestservice.rest.RestBookService.createBook(RestBookService.java:44)
'
```

Not sure why this exception because it is already in persistentcontext.

### **EDIT2**

@HankCa suggested I did the following change.

Removed

```
@Context
protected UriInfo uriInfo;
```

And updated the method signature as

```
@POST
public Response createBook(Book book, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
```

And the service is working as expected. Thanks HankCa for your help.

Comment: I have added the project on github. Here is the link. https://github.com/shashanksdixit/s-git/tree/d41c56e0a786f3db0cd99cf0b2bdcb0fd2269891/bookrestservice

Comment: Inviting @HankCa since he had a similar issue earlier. Kindly take a look, if I am missing anything here.

Comment: Try losing the UriInfo to see what difference that makes.

Comment: @HankCa. You are the man! I removed UriInfo and I was able to create and get the rows by restful service. Then I injected UriInfo in the method instead of class and it worked. So the answer to this question is remove UriInfo from class and get it as a method parameter.

Comment: Congrats!  So my answer was correct, could you tick it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I stared at this one for far too long and my solution was as you found at [Why is my Jersey JAX-RS server throwing a IllegalStateException about not being in RequestScope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119108/why-is-my-jersey-jax-rs-server-throwing-a-illegalstateexception-about-not-being).  This was a year ago and I haven't hit it again (though I have been out of EJB land for a while) so I'll give it my best shot.

Specifically I would make these mods:

- Add `@RequestScoped`
- Put the `@Context UriInfo uriInfo` in the method or class.  In the end i seemed to have gone in the method like:

This is code (and this is a line to separate the list from the code so the code shows as code!)

```
@Path("/user")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@RequestScoped
public class UserResource {    
    ...
    @PermitAll
    @POST
    public Response signupUser(CreateUserRequest request, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        AuthenticatedUserToken token = userService.createUser(request, Role.authenticated);
        verificationTokenService.sendEmailRegistrationToken(token.getUserId());
        URI location = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(token.getUserId()).build();
        return Response.created(location).entity(token).build();
    }
```

I hope that helps!

Cheers,

bbos

Comment: Another thing I would try is JBoss Wildfly (http://www.wildfly.org/) as an alternative Open Source web app server (its not OS itself but is mostly based on OS components).  It took 15 months for a new version of Glassfish to be released and although I'm hopeful that it's support has gained traction, I'd be comparing alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for quickly coming here and devoting some time to this. I will modify the code and check it out.

Comment: I have added the EDIT1 after trying RequestScoped annotation. I am still getting an exception. Although not same, but still weird. :(